# Git workflow / practices for a small project (flowchart in png)

Tags: project-management, programming-practices, version-control, git, workflows

I'm trying to come up with a personal workflow. I've put together a flowchart of the hypothetical lifespan of a release: one developer pushing to a public github repo + a friend helping with some feature and fixing a bug.

Is this a reasonable approach to version control?

The main idea is to keep the public repo tidy:

- Each new release gets on its own branch until it's finally tagged in the master branch when it's finished.
- All work is done on "feature" or "hotfix" branches, never on an actual release branch, to prevent anomalies.
- Merges to higher-level branches are always rebased or squashed (to avoid clutter).

If it's overkill I don't mind because the whole point is for me is to learn skills I might need for a larger project. The only problem would be if I'm doing something flat out wrong or unnecessary.

**edit 2:** fixed bad idea in the original flowchart and made it a bit easier to navigate.

[image: v1.1]

Comment: @ClintNash Thanks! I updated the image to fix the `--squash` mistake and added a grid to make it easier to follow.

Comment: "Merges to higher-level branches are always rebased or squashed (to avoid clutter)." Sometimes I feel this adds more clutter, since the history doesn't match what really happened.

Comment: check this out http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: I think my brain just exploded O.O

Answer (score 3):

What I see a lot in the git/github community is this

branches
master
develop

You and contributors work primarily in develop, but someone may have an idea or new feature, so you create a topic branch like git checkout -b user_comments.

Then as you progress through the development you push to master once you git a version you are happy with and tag that in the master branch as 1.0 or 1.1.2 etc ( look up semantic versioning )

Comment: I was not aware of proper semantic versioning. I mus admit up until today I've been numbering things without any real method to it. I'll start using it from now on. Thanks for the tip! -- website: http://semver.org/